# Can I buy land if I didn't read the courier's letter?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I have been playing Skyrim on the PS3 and recently bought the Hearthfire DLC.

I was then given a note by a courier about adoption and house building. I was smart enough to not read it and then drop it when I was carrying too much to run (not realizing the weight was 0).

Now I have lost the note and can't activate the quest that lets you buy the land. Any suggestions on what I should do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The note doesn't matter much, you can just go directly to the person selling land and buy it from them if you satisfy their requirements.

The Jarl of Dawnstar and the stewards of Falkreath and Morthal all have plots of land for sale. You can only purchase Morthal land if you are a thane of that hold, though the other two also have quest requirements. You can buy all 3 plots and build 3 new houses.

Each of the 3 plots costs 5,000.

Comment: I have tried going to the npc in but when start talking to them nothing pops up for me to say.

Comment: Are you approaching the right NPC and do you satisfy their requirements?

Comment: Im pretty sure it's the correct NPC, and what are their requirements?

Comment: Were you able to buy the land? If so, what was the problem? If you consider your question answered, you can click the checkmark next to an answer to mark it as answered.

Comment: The only difference is the topic of land for sale.