# How soon does the plot of land letter arrive for morthal thane?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

How much time does the courier take to give a letter to you after you've become Thane of Morthal?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't get a letter -- you need to ask the Jarl to buy the plot.

Comment: Have you tried talking to the housecarl in the Jarl’s court?

Comment: @amaranth is right. I meant the housecarl, not the Jarl.

Comment: Related: [Can I buy land if I didn't read the courier's letter?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/118963/4797)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to wait for the letter in order to buy the plot of land. The courier sometimes gives it to you at a random time. But you don't need the letter to buy the plot of land. First become a Thane by completing the Jarl's quests and helping people. Then, you talk to the housecarl for the plot of land. You don't need the letter about the Land.